# Lua string concatenation within table constructor

Tags: constructor, lua, string-concatenation, lua-table

I'm trying to initialize a table of default properties for my script, and I'm facing the following scenario:

```
_property_table = {

    k1 = "val1",
    k2 = "val2",
    k3 = k1 .. "val3",

}

print(_property_table.k3)
```

When trying to concatenate k1 within the table constructor, lua fails with the following error:

```
_impl error: [string "main.lua"]:10: attempt to concatenate global 'k1' (a nil value)
```

Is this behavior expected, or am I missing something?

I'm fairly new to Lua, so any tips or suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behaviour is expected: `k1` is not a variable name, `k1 =` is simply a shortcut for `["k1"] =` inside a table expression. There are two basic solutions:

1. Use a variable:

   ```
   local k1 = "val1"
   _property_table = {
       k1 = k1,
       k2 = "val2",
       k3 = k1 .. "val3",
   }
   ```
2. Assign `k3` after the table creation:

   ```
   _property_table = {
       k1 = "val1,
       k2 = "val2",
   }
   _property_table.k3 = _property_table.k1 .. "val3"
   ```

Comment: Thank you, I went on and followed the second approach you described.